# Как узнать, имеет ли класс определенного родителя?

Tags: c++, qt, классы, qt5, наследование

Как узнать, имеет ли класс определенного родителя?

Ситуация: хочу написать обобщённую функцию типа `std::make_unique()`, для того чтобы создавать объекты библиотеки Qt одинаково со стандартными объектами, т.е. в деструкторе для обычных объектов вызывать `delete`, а для объектов Qt -- нет. Так вот, для проверки, является ли объект объектом Qt, хочу проверить имеет ли он родителя `QObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого существует специальный трейт `std::is_base_of<QObject, Derived>::value`